# Windows 10 Task scheduler not triggering when connected to a specified network connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-scheduler

I have set these settings in the Task Scheduler in a Windows 10 machine (updated till version 1709)

**Triggers**

- Log:      Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operation
- Source:   Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile
- Event ID: 10000

**Conditions**

- Set *Start only if the following network connection is available* to the specified network

If I set *Start only if the following network connection is available* to *Any connection*, the task runs fine. However, if I specify the network connection, it does not run even when I connect the machine to a specified network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on Win10 1903. My work around is to set XML custom event filtering in Triggers:

```
<QueryList>
 <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational">
  <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational">
   *[System[(Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=10000)]]
   and
   *[EventData[Data[@Name="Name"] and (Data="SomeNetworkName")]] 
  </Select>
 </Query>
</QueryList>
```

In upper code you have to replace "SomeNetworkName" with your network name.

Conditions:
Set "Start only if the following network connection is available" to Any connection

Comment: This solves the issue but could be elaborated. I found a blog post that does that: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/trigger-launch-program-script-connecting-to-specific-network/

Answer (score 0):

To add to Samo27's nice answer, I was trying to get this running but the task did not trigger and I could not understand why.... until I found under the Conditions tab "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power". Of course I was unplugged and only using my battery.. When I unticked it, the task finally ran. If it can save some time for some one else also making this (silly) mistake.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).